# How to plug Braintree powered by Paypal, Recurring Billing in WooCommerce Subscription?

Tags: paypal, woocommerce, braintree, recurring-billing, woocommerce-subscriptions

I need help regarding setting up `WooCommerce Subscription plugin` for using a recurring payment for a Website and to facilitate Payments for the same I am using `PayPal Powered by Braintree - WooCommerce`.

The way I have set up the plugin is as follows:

Using the WooCommerce Subscription Plugin I am creating the required plans which have Recurring Payments on the Website.

And for payment processing we are using `Braintree powered by PayPal plugin`.

Issue I am facing is the `Braintree payment gateway` is processing the payment as Recurring payment (Subscription), but on next due date of payment the customer is not charged automatically and the website owner has to manually charge the customer.

So basically I want to process the payment automatically for a subscription without the website owner having to charge each subscription manually on due date.

**Setting for subscription plans on `WooCommerce` Subscription plugin:**

[image]

Settings on the Braintree powered by PayPal plugin.

[image]

[image]

**Few questions**

1. Is the setup mentioned above correct or am I missing something?

Currently the Plans to be shown on the website are being created using the WooCommerece Subscription plugin, now do I need to create subscription plans on braintree panel first and then link those plans with Wordpress using the braintree api? Or creating the plans on Subscription Plugin is fine using Braintree as just a payment gateway.

2. Is there anything to do with reference transactions, do I need to set up reference transactions on the Subscription module?
3. Is it necessary to enable reference transactions to process the payment automatically?

I have tried different approaches without much luck, so any help in setting this up will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Hi did you solved your issue ? i still facing some issue same like this